# Cannot retrieve CSS value within AngularJS directive

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs

I've been trying to use the code on [this blog](http://www.dnasir.com/2013/10/09/display-mode-detection-for-responsive-websites-using-angularjs/) to have access to a value describing the size of the browser, which is to be used within `AngularJS`. I want to be able to do this so I can set routing states based on the screen size (I am using `ui-router` for that).

This part of the directive retrieves `<span>` elements that have been added in the index.html file. Each `<span>` element has a class which describes the size of the browser (in my case `'small','medium','large'`). With a CSS, media queries are used to set `'display:none'` of the `<span>` elements based on the size of the browser window. So if the size of the browser is smaller than 320px, both .medium and .large classes will have `display:none`. The directive *should* check the display value of these  elements and find out which of them does not have it, thus returning the name of the active class.

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
       var markers = elem.find('span');
       function isVisible(element) {
           return element
           && element.style.display != 'none'
           && element.offsetWidth
           && element.offsetHeight;
       }

       function update() {
           angular.forEach(markers, function (element) {
           if (isVisible(element)) {
               scope.dnDisplayMode = element.className;
               return false;
           }
       });
   }

   var t;
   angular.element($window).bind('resize', function() {
       clearTimeout(t);
       t = setTimeout(function() {
           update();
           scope.$apply();
       }, 300);
   });

   update();
```

}

The problem that I have encountered is in the function `isVisible`. With every  element, the value of `element.style.display` is 'null'. I have used Firefox's and Chrome's element inspector and found out that the  elements have either a value of `'display:inline-block'` or `'display:none'`. But AngularJS uses its embedded jQuery to retrieve the value from the element. To do that it goes to the style of the element and tries to find the display value. But within the style attribute of all the selected elements, all values of that style are empty.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean `CSSStyleDeclaration` attribute? What are you trying to access? Add the code in the question, that Plunker is utterly useless!

Comment: Sorry, I just found out that CSSStyleDeclaration is Chrome specific. I have updated the question to hopefully be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

your 'elem' variable is a jqLite object, to access native dom properties, like style.display you'll need to use element[0].style.display in your isVisible function.